# Process csv file of 222008k lines inserted in an Oracle table using PLSQL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a zip file into table in blob column:

[image]

I have created a procedure which performs the following steps:

1. Get file corresponding to process in progress
2. Get list of files inside zip file
3. Loop to iterate each file
4. Convert BLOB content to CLOB
5. This for each separates the CLOB content line by line when it detects chr(10) using an xml table
6. This for each separates the rows obtained from each line into columns
7. Insert the separated data into the final table

this is my code:

```
PROCEDURE unzip_and_insert_cv027_sp (
        p_id_proceso_oic IN VARCHAR2,
        p_file_name      IN VARCHAR2,
        out_result       OUT VARCHAR2,
        out_message      OUT VARCHAR2
    ) IS

     --
        v_doc          BLOB;
        v_file_content CLOB;
        zip_files      as_zip.file_list;
    BEGIN
    --1. Get file corresponding to process in progress
        SELECT
            file_content
        INTO v_doc
        FROM
            journals_cv027_files
        WHERE
                file_name = p_file_name
            AND id_proceso_oic = p_id_proceso_oic;

        --2. Get list of files inside zip file
        zip_files := as_zip.get_file_list(v_doc);
        
        --3. Loop to iterate each file
        FOR i IN zip_files.first()..zip_files.last LOOP
            --4. Convert BLOB content to CLOB
            SELECT
                blob_to_clob_fn(as_zip.get_file(v_doc, zip_files(i)))
            INTO v_file_content
            FROM
                dual;
            --

            --5. This for each separates the CLOB content line by line when it detects chr(10) using an xml table
            FOR linea IN (
                SELECT
                    TRIM(column_value) l
                FROM
                    dual,
                    xmltable ( ( '"'
                                 || replace(v_file_content, CHR(10), '","')
                                 || '"' ) )
            ) LOOP
                --6. This for each separates the rows obtained from each line into columns
                FOR i2 IN (
                    SELECT
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1), ',')      status,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 2), ',')   ledger_name,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 3), ',')   accounting_date,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 4), ',')   currency_code,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 5), ',')   date_created,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 6), ',')   created_by,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 7), ',')   actual_flag,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 8), ',')   user_je_category_name,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 9), ',')   user_je_source_name,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 10), ',')  entered_dr,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 11), ',')  entered_cr,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 12), ',')  reference1,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 13), ',')  reference2,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 14), ',')  reference3,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 15), ',')  reference4,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 16), ',')  reference5,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 42), ',')  code_combination_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 43), ',')  group_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 44), ',')  object_version_number,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 45), ',')  chart_of_accounts_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 46), ',')  segment1,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 47), ',')  segment2,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 48), ',')  segment3,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 49), ',')  segment4,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 50), ',')  segment5,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 51), ',')  segment6,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 52), ',')  segment7,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 53), ',')  segment8,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 54), ',')  segment9,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 55), ',')  segment10,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 56), ',')  segment11,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 57), ',')  segment12,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 58), ',')  segment13,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 59), ',')  segment14,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 60), ',')  segment15,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 61), ',')  segment16,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 62), ',')  segment17,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 63), ',')  segment18,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 64), ',')  segment19,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 65), ',')  segment20,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 66), ',')  segment21,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 67), ',')  segment22,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 68), ',')  segment23,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 69), ',')  segment24,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 70), ',')  segment25,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 71), ',')  segment26,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 72), ',')  segment27,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 73), ',')  segment28,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 74), ',')  segment29,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 75), ',')  segment30,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 76), ',')  attribute1,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 77), ',')  attribute2,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 78), ',')  attribute3,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 79), ',')  attribute4,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 89), ',')  attribute5,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 81), ',')  attribute6,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 82), ',')  attribute7,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 83), ',')  attribute8,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 84), ',')  attribute9,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 85), ',')  attribute10,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 86), ',')  attribute11,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 87), ',')  attribute12,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 88), ',')  attribute13,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 89), ',')  attribute14,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 90), ',')  attribute15,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 91), ',')  attribute16,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 92), ',')  attribute17,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 93), ',')  attribute18,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 94), ',')  attribute19,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 95), ',')  attribute20,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 96), ',')  accounted_cr,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 97), ',')  accounted_dr,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 98), ',')  set_of_books_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 99), ',')  currency_conversion_rate,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 100), ',') reference_date,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 101), ',') transaction_date,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 102), ',') period_name,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 103), ',') user_currency_conversion_type,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 104), ',') currency_conversion_date,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 105), ',') ledger_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 106), ',') encumbrance_type_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 107), ',') budget_version_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 108), ',') je_batch_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 109), ',') je_header_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 110), ',') je_line_num,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 111), ',') functional_currency_code,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 112), ',') date_created_in_gl,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 113), ',') warning_code,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 114), ',') status_description,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 115), ',') request_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 116), ',') subledger_doc_sequence_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 117), ',') subledger_doc_sequence_value,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 118), ',') gl_sl_link_id,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 119), ',') gl_sl_link_table,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 120), ',') invoice_date,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 121), ',') tax_code,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 122), ',') invoice_identifier,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 123), ',') invoice_amount,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 124), ',') ussgl_transaction_code,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 125), ',') descr_flex_error_message,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 126), ',') jgzz_recon_ref,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 127), ',') balancing_segment_value,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 128), ',') management_segment_value,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 129), ',') funds_reserved_flag,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 130), ',') code_combination_id_interim,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 131), ',') stat_amount,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 132), ',') average_journal_flag,
                        rtrim(regexp_substr(linea.l, '[^,]*,', 1, 133), ',') originating_bal_seg_value
                    FROM
                        dual
                ) LOOP
                    CASE i2.status
                        WHEN 'STATUS' THEN
                            dbms_output.put_line('Se omiten los cabeceros');
                        ELSE
                            --7. Insert the separated data into the final table
                            INSERT INTO journals_cv027_data (
                                status,
                                ledger_name,
                                accounting_date,
                                currency_code,
                                date_created,
                                created_by,
                                actual_flag,
                                user_je_category_name,
                                user_je_source_name,
                                entered_dr,
                                entered_cr,
                                reference1,
                                reference2,
                                reference3,
                                reference4,
                                reference5,                                   
                                code_combination_id,
                                group_id,
                                object_version_number,
                                chart_of_accounts_id,
                                segment1,
                                segment2,
                                segment3,
                                segment4,
                                segment5,
                                segment6,
                                segment7,
                                segment8,
                                segment9,
                                segment10,
                                segment11,
                                segment12,
                                segment13,
                                segment14,
                                segment15,
                                segment16,
                                segment17,
                                segment18,
                                segment19,
                                segment20,
                                segment21,
                                segment22,
                                segment23,
                                segment24,
                                segment25,
                                segment26,
                                segment27,
                                segment28,
                                segment29,
                                segment30,
                                attribute1,
                                attribute2,
                                attribute3,
                                attribute4,
                                attribute5,
                                attribute6,
                                attribute7,
                                attribute8,
                                attribute9,
                                attribute10,
                                attribute11,
                                attribute12,
                                attribute13,
                                attribute14,
                                attribute15,
                                attribute16,
                                attribute17,
                                attribute18,
                                attribute19,
                                attribute20,
                                accounted_cr,
                                accounted_dr,
                                set_of_books_id,
                                currency_conversion_rate,
                                reference_date,
                                transaction_date,
                                period_name,
                                user_currency_conversion_type,
                                currency_conversion_date,
                                ledger_id,
                                encumbrance_type_id,
                                budget_version_id,
                                je_batch_id,
                                je_header_id,
                                je_line_num,
                                functional_currency_code,
                                date_created_in_gl,
                                warning_code,
                                status_description,
                                request_id,
                                subledger_doc_sequence_id,
                                subledger_doc_sequence_value,
                                gl_sl_link_id,
                                gl_sl_link_table,
                                invoice_date,
                                tax_code,
                                invoice_identifier,
                                invoice_amount,
                                ussgl_transaction_code,
                                descr_flex_error_message,
                                jgzz_recon_ref,
                                balancing_segment_value,
                                management_segment_value,
                                funds_reserved_flag,
                                code_combination_id_interim,
                                stat_amount,
                                average_journal_flag,
                                originating_bal_seg_value,
                                id_proceso_oic
                            ) VALUES (
                                i2.status,
                                i2.ledger_name,
                                i2.accounting_date,
                                i2.currency_code,
                                i2.date_created,
                                i2.created_by,
                                i2.actual_flag,
                                i2.user_je_category_name,
                                i2.user_je_source_name,
                                i2.entered_dr,
                                i2.entered_cr,
                                i2.reference1,
                                i2.reference2,
                                i2.reference3,
                                i2.reference4,
                                i2.reference5,
                                i2.reference6,
                                i2.reference7,
                                i2.reference8,
                                i2.reference9,
                                i2.reference10,
                                i2.reference11,
                                i2.reference12,
                                i2.reference13,
                                i2.reference14,
                                i2.reference15,
                                i2.reference16,
                                i2.reference17,
                                i2.reference18,
                                i2.reference19,
                                i2.reference20,
                                i2.reference21,
                                i2.reference22,
                                i2.reference23,
                                i2.reference24,
                                i2.reference25,
                                i2.reference26,
                                i2.reference27,
                                i2.reference28,
                                i2.reference29,
                                i2.reference30,
                                i2.code_combination_id,
                                i2.group_id,
                                i2.object_version_number,
                                i2.chart_of_accounts_id,
                                i2.segment1,
                                i2.segment2,
                                i2.segment3,
                                i2.segment4,
                                i2.segment5,
                                i2.segment6,
                                i2.segment7,
                                i2.segment8,
                                i2.segment9,
                                i2.segment10,
                                i2.segment11,
                                i2.segment12,
                                i2.segment13,
                                i2.segment14,
                                i2.segment15,
                                i2.segment16,
                                i2.segment17,
                                i2.segment18,
                                i2.segment19,
                                i2.segment20,
                                i2.segment21,
                                i2.segment22,
                                i2.segment23,
                                i2.segment24,
                                i2.segment25,
                                i2.segment26,
                                i2.segment27,
                                i2.segment28,
                                i2.segment29,
                                i2.segment30,
                                i2.attribute1,
                                i2.attribute2,
                                i2.attribute3,
                                i2.attribute4,
                                i2.attribute5,
                                i2.attribute6,
                                i2.attribute7,
                                i2.attribute8,
                                i2.attribute9,
                                i2.attribute10,
                                i2.attribute11,
                                i2.attribute12,
                                i2.attribute13,
                                i2.attribute14,
                                i2.attribute15,
                                i2.attribute16,
                                i2.attribute17,
                                i2.attribute18,
                                i2.attribute19,
                                i2.attribute20,
                                i2.accounted_cr,
                                i2.accounted_dr,
                                i2.set_of_books_id,
                                i2.currency_conversion_rate,
                                i2.reference_date,
                                i2.transaction_date,
                                i2.period_name,
                                i2.user_currency_conversion_type,
                                i2.currency_conversion_date,
                                i2.ledger_id,
                                i2.encumbrance_type_id,
                                i2.budget_version_id,
                                i2.je_batch_id,
                                i2.je_header_id,
                                i2.je_line_num,
                                i2.functional_currency_code,
                                i2.date_created_in_gl,
                                i2.warning_code,
                                i2.status_description,
                                i2.request_id,
                                i2.subledger_doc_sequence_id,
                                i2.subledger_doc_sequence_value,
                                i2.gl_sl_link_id,
                                i2.gl_sl_link_table,
                                i2.invoice_date,
                                i2.tax_code,
                                i2.invoice_identifier,
                                i2.invoice_amount,
                                i2.ussgl_transaction_code,
                                i2.descr_flex_error_message,
                                i2.jgzz_recon_ref,
                                i2.balancing_segment_value,
                                i2.management_segment_value,
                                i2.funds_reserved_flag,
                                i2.code_combination_id_interim,
                                i2.stat_amount,
                                i2.average_journal_flag,
                                i2.originating_bal_seg_value,
                                p_id_proceso_oic
                            );

                            COMMIT;
                    END CASE;
                END LOOP;
            END LOOP;

        END LOOP;

    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            out_result := 'ERROR: ' || sqlerrm;
            out_message := dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
    END unzip_and_insert_cv027_sp;
```

With a file of 3,000k lines it works correctly but with a file of 222,008k lines the procedure only runs up to step number 4 and then throws an error.

How can I optimize the procedure after step 4 so that it is capable of processing a large volume of information?

It is important to mention that I cannot use an external table because I have not configured the communication with directories in the database.

The database version is 19C.

Comment: **a)** "... runs up to step number 4 and then throws an error" - which error? **b)** "... because I have not configured the communication with directories" - if you think external table would help, then creating a directory is really the least of all problems you might have in this task. **c)** I'd move COMMIT out of loop.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot **a)** Error: No more data to read from socket, generated when trying to execute step 5. **b)** The client does not have access to the database configuration therefore setting directories is not an option for us **c** I'll keep it in mind